# Google Analytics Referral from 301 Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

We have a site where we use some custom javascript to rollup all subdomains and external domains into one domain. That is all working. However, the main domain shows as a referral and is breaking the page flow.

We use ISAPI ReWriter in IIS to 301 redirect all traffic to "example.com" to "www.example.com".

Then on all sites, both internal and external, we use the same universal code to determine whether the domain should be set or if the links should be pushed.

Questions:
1) Is it correct to set the domain to ".example.com" (in _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com']);) if we want to track the subdomains blog.example.com, store.example.com, etc.example.com?

2) What if we redirected the example.com site in IIS to www.example.com instead of using ISAPI ReWrite?

3) Why is example.com showing up as a referral and how can stop that?

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXETC']);
      var locText = window.location.host;

        // vars to check domain
        var exampleDomain = new RegExp('www.example.com', 'i');
        var exampleRedirect = new RegExp('^example.com', 'i');

        //check if we are on the main domain
        if(exampleDomain.test(locText) || exampleRedirect.test(locText)){

            //Roll Up (domain and subdomains)
              _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
            _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com']);

        } else {
            _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
            _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', window.location.host]);
              _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        }

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {

        // load the ga.js file.  This happens last now.
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

        // this function is an exclusion blacklist of sites we don't want to push
        function donotpushlinks(linkpattern)
        {
            var blacklist = [
                "twitter"
                ,"facebook"
                ,"tumblr"
                ,"youtube"
                ,"pinterest"
                ,"infantino"
                ,"exampleuk"
            ];
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + blacklist.join("|") + '\\b', 'i');

            return(linkpattern.match(re) != null);
        }

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //for each anchor on the page, check whether we need to push
        jQuery('a').each(function() {
               var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
               //do not touch javascript links
               var b = new RegExp('^javascript', 'i');
                  var c = new RegExp('javascript', 'i');
                  //test against the blacklist
               var d = donotpushlinks(this.href);

               //1) check if link is not internal
               if(!a.test(this.href))
               {
                   //2) Check if it is javascript
                   if (!b.test(this.href) || !c.test(this.href))
                   {
                           //3) check if it not one of the blackklist test patterns
                           if (!d)
                           {
                               //console.log(d + " " + this.href);
                               jQuery(this).click(function(event)
                               {
                                   event.preventDefault();
                                   event.stopPropagation();

                                   // Google it
                                   _gaq.push(['_link',this.href]);

                                    return false;
                               });
                           }
                           //3) Otherwise, it is a link to an external site outside of example. Open in new window with NO tracking
                           else
                           {

                            jQuery(this).click(function(event)
                               {
                                   event.preventDefault();
                                   event.stopPropagation();
                                   window.open(this.href, '_blank');
                                    return false;
                               });

                           }
                   }
                   //2) Otherwise, it is javascript, so leave it alone
                   else{

                           }
               }
               //1) otherwise it is internal, so leave it alone
               else
               {
                //console.log('Internal link: ' + this.href);  
               }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fan of using _setDomainName 'none', it has a few drawbacks.

However, I would start by revisiting the choice of `window.location.host` in favor of `window.location.hostname` for `_addIgnoredRef`, even suggest to do use `window.location.hostname.split('.')[window.location.hostname.split('.').length]`

The issue with `host` is that it contains the port number, thus it restricts the chances that it matches the referral value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: What alternative to setDomainName none is there? That block is for external sites that need to have the link pushed from one domain to another.

Comment: `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.'+ window.location.hostname]);` would do what you need without doing an implicit _setAllowHash false line 'none' does

Comment: But that would add the external sites to another cookies, right? They want the subdomains to rollup to the main domain -- as if there was only one site.

Comment: If you need that navigation to subdomains / main domain be continous, you should use `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com']);` on all sites, instead of 'none'.
If you have NO `_setDomainName` today on example.com, then you should remove the leading dot, NOT ot reset cookies of the main domain.

Comment: example.com is a 301 redirect from an IIS Isapi Rewriter module. If you type example.com/store it 301's you to www.example.com/store. So with the leading dot, if I remove that what will happen to blog.example.com and store.example.com in terms of the cookie? My understanding is that tracking across lower-level sub-domains will still be tracked in the main ".example.com" cookie. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want. Cookies handle marketing source data and visit scope, not UA number. Using the same or a different UA allows /disallows rollup. Using `'_setDomainName','.example.com'` everywhere allows a single session over all subdomains.

Comment: I'll try setting external domains to .example.com and see what happens. The goal is to make all external traffic "direct" and to persist the cookie through setallowLinker _gaq.push(['_link',this.href]);
pushes on external links.

Comment: So, no change. Perhaps a clue is that direct traffic shows as "example.com/" while the referral traffic shows as "example.com" without the slash. What could this mean?